# Compiler says that "head" is not declared: LinkedList

Tags: c++, algorithm

I define my Node as a struct and trying to get it. But when I run my code compiler says that "head", "tail" was not declared. Am I define it wrongly?

Tried to use template but it didn't work;

[image]

[image]

Comment: No images of text please, copy paste as text instead.

Comment: A hint though: The functions, are they really *member* functions?

Comment: You can use the {} button on the toolbar to form a code block. Select the text and press the {} button

Answer (score 2):

You are having head and tail declared inside class List as it's private member fields. But you are accessing them from methods outside the class. The compiler is throwing errors because of that.

Comment: I removed private declaration, still have this problem

Comment: Can you please add the updated, complete code as text in the question? It would help us understand the problem better. Please don't forget to include new set of errors also alongwith the code.

Comment: struct Node
{
 int data;
 Node *next;
};

class List{
  Node *head, *tail;
 public:
  List(){
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
  }
}; Still have exactly the same errors.

Comment: If we do not specify access modifiers for any class's member field in C++, by default, they are treated as private. Hence, the code that you added as comment is not too different from the one you added in the picture. Note that in a class, members are by default private while in a struct, they are by default, public.

Comment: Also one suggestion from my end would be to move the methods into the list class so that head and tail are accessible. The suggestion from lucieon about logic change still remains valid IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

In the `insertFront` function, you have coded

```
head = node
node->next = head;
```

This is wrong. `head` is the only access you have to the remaining linked list. By doing `head = node`, you lose access to the rest of the list. and doing `node->next = head` after that essentially points the node to itself. It should be done in reverse.

```
node->next = head;
head = node;
```

Another mistake in the `insertBack` function. `prev` is not declared in `struct Node`. The right way to insert at `tail` is

```
tail->next = node;
tail = node;
```